# Inserting DATETIME into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am having a problem inserting DATETIME into MySQL using PHP.

First, I am fetching a date from the news table:

```
$statement = $db->query("SELECT utcPublishedDate FROM News WHERE idNews = $newsID");
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$utcPublishedDate = $row["utcPublishedDate"];
```

Then I am doing some date manipulation on that date due to some code requirements, eventually this date is changing to something else.

Now, I have to update the table, so:

```
$statement = $db->query("UPDATE News SET utcPublishedDate = $utcPublishedDate WHERE idNews = $newsID");
```

This is causing an error. If I do this:

```
$statement = $db->query("UPDATE News SET utcPublishedDate = NOW() WHERE idNews = $newsID");
```

The statement will execute without a problem.

Now, how do I solve the error I am getting? Obviously It is something to do with the fact there are spaces in my DATETIME field. Suggestions please? Thanks.

Comment: What does this variable `$utcPublishedDate` contain? Does it contain valid data time in the valid format? Additionally, what error did you get, regarding the second case as you mentioned?

Comment: As described in my first code snippet, $utcPublishedDate in PHP takes the value from utcPublishedDate in MySQL. This is a DATETIME field in MySQL.

Comment: Wrap $utcPublishedDate in single quotes in your UPDATE, as you would a string

Comment: Thanks mark, but would that affect my date?

Comment: You are using PDO yet putting data directly in the query?

Comment: I know I should prepare, bind, then execute, but this is internal code only. However, good point. I will change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing:

```
$statement = $db->query("UPDATE News SET utcPublishedDate = $utcPublishedDate WHERE idNews = $newsID");
```

to:

```
$statement = $db->query("UPDATE News SET utcPublishedDate = '$utcPublishedDate' WHERE idNews = $newsID");
```

Comment: Will try that, but will it affect my date (I mean, it will not convert it to a string or anything!). Apologies for the not-so-smart question!

Comment: No it won't; but 2012-11-8 (without quotes) will be interpreted as a subtraction giving a numeric value of 1993

Answer (score 0):

Convert the DATETIME via php first so that it will be Mysql valid datetime. Use this:

```
$utcPublishedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($utcPublishedDate));   $statement = $db->query("UPDATE News SET utcPublishedDate = '$utcPublishedDate' WHERE idNews = $newsID");
```

Cheers